# Vanishing of the Zariski cohomology $H^n(X,\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}_m])$ for $n>1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth and irreducible variety over a field.

> Does the Zariski cohomology $H^n(X,\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}_m])$ vanish for $n>1$?

Here $\mathbb{Z}[-]\colon Set\to Ab$ is (the Zariski sheafification of) the free abelian group functor applied sectionwise to the sheaf $\mathbb{G}_m$.

This guess comes from the analogous situation ''without'' the free abelian group which is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096650/k-x-o-x-is-a-flasque-sheaf-for-smooth-variety-over-mathbbc): We have
$$
 H^n(X,\mathbb{G}_m) = 0 \quad \mbox{for $n>1$}
$$
by the following argument. The exact sequence
$$
1\to \mathbb{G}_m \to K_X^\times \to \mathrm{CaDiv} \to 1
$$
of Zariski sheaves (defining Cartier divisors $\mathrm{CaDiv}$) is a resolution by flasque sheaves: The constant sheaf $K_X^\times$ is flasque and since Cartier divisors are Weil divisors $\mathrm{CaDiv}=\mathrm{WDiv}$ on the regular $X$, the sheaf $\mathrm{CaDiv}$ is flasque as well.

Now also $\mathbb{Z}[K_X^\times]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{WDiv}]$ are flasque Zariski sheaves but the sequence
$$
1\to \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}_m] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[K_X^\times] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{WDiv}]
$$
may not be an exact sequence of Zariski sheaves, I guess: One only gets a stalkwise surjection
$$
\mathbb{Z}[K_X^\times]/\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}_m] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{WDiv}]
$$
(Note that although $\mathbb{Z}[-]$ preserves colimits/quotients of sets, this may not be true for quotients in abelian groups) and I don't have an idea on how to control the kernel. Maybe, there is an easier way to see that
$$
\mathbb{Z}[K_X^\times]/\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}_m] 
$$
is a flasque Zariski-sheaf. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you!